# Putting all checked checkbox id's into an string

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes with different id's and I want to get all of them into an array like this:

var my_string = "champion='id1' OR champion='id2' OR champion='id3' OR champion='id4'"

you can say that I have a html like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id1"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id2"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id3"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id4"/></li>
</ul>
```

How would I do it with jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your particular example.  It queries for all `input` elements, builds an array with "champion=*id*", then joins the array with the word "OR."

```js
var checks= document.querySelectorAll('input');
var s = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < checks.length ; i++) {
  s.push("champion='"+checks[i].id+"'");
}
var my_string = s.join(' OR ');
alert(my_string);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id1"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id2"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id3"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id4"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this worked out. Also this is the first and last answer I tried, I'm pretty sure other answers are right as well, just haven't tried them out :)

Comment: Many of the other answers are quite good.  The main difference is that some assume you're interested in which boxes are checked, and I assumed you just wanted a list of IDs in that particular format.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the ids of all inputs that are checkboxes on the page into an array containing the value of the id.

```
$(function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i, v) {
        arr.push($(v).attr("id"));
    });
})
```

Comment: And to create a string instead use `arr.concat('champion=', $(v).attr("id"), ' Or ');` and then chop off the last or after the `.each()` with `substr()` or `slice()` (probably rename arr though ;) Nte: untested but should be close.

Comment: @sareed:  Joining the array on the word **OR** saves the trouble of using `substr()`.

Comment: very true missed that one. Sometimes I just type too quickly :)

Comment: In jQuery, the second argument on the callback to `each` is of the type `Element`. So you dont need to turn that element into a jQuery object first and than use a method to pick the ID – instead read it directly. Example: Instead of `$(v).attr("id")` better use `v.id` to read the element ID.

Answer (score 0):

To get all checked boxes you can use the according CSS selector:

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked' );
console.log( checkedBoxes );
```

At this point you have a [DOM NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which you can iterate over directly or transfer the entries into an array.

```
// print all ID's
for( var i = checkedBoxes.length; i--; ) {
    console.log( checkedBoxes[i].id );
}

// store ID's into flat array
var idList = [];
for( var i = checkedBoxes.length; i--; ) {
    idList.push( checkedBoxes[i].id );
}
console.log( idList );
```

As you see, you don't even need jQuery for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
function calc(){
    var q = ""
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        if (q != "") q += " or "
        q+= " champion = '" + $(this).attr("id") + "'"
    })
    return "var myString = \"" + q + "\"";
}
```

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/nfryb2wj/

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
var champions = [];

function getChampions() {
  champions = $('li input:checked').map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
  $('#x').html( JSON.stringify(champions) );
}
  
$('input').on('change',getChampions);

getChampions();
```

```css
input:before {
  content: attr(id);
  margin-left: 1.5em;

}
#x {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #FED;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id1"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id2"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id3"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="id4"/></li>
</ul>

<pre id="x" title="debug"></pre>
```